# generating same date as bill date php

Tags: php

```
$contract_start_date = strtotime('2016-01-01');
$contract_end_date = strtotime('2016-12-01');

$contract_start_date_last_date = date('t', $contract_start_date);
echo "contract last date of any start month: ".$contract_start_date_last_date."<br />";
$contract_end_date_last_date = date('t', $contract_end_date);
echo "contract last date of any end month: ".$contract_end_date_last_date."<br />";


$no_of_months = 1 + (date("Y", $contract_end_date) - date("Y", $contract_start_date)) * 12;
$no_of_months += date("m", $contract_end_date) - date("m", $contract_start_date);
$no_of_days =  $contract_start_date_last_date - date("d", $contract_start_date);
echo $no_of_days."<br />";
echo $no_of_months."<br />";



$total_contract_value = 1000;
$no_of_bookings = 1;
$no_of_records = ($no_of_months / $no_of_bookings);
echo $no_of_records."<br />";
$contract_value = ($total_contract_value / $no_of_records);
echo $contract_value."<br />";
$initial_contract_value_for_first_month = ($contract_value / $no_of_days);
echo $initial_contract_value_for_first_month."<br />";

for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_records; $i++){
    $proceed = false;
    $calculated_records = intval($i * $no_of_bookings);
    echo $calculated_records."<br />";
    $contract_date = strtotime("+".$calculated_records." months", $contract_start_date);
    echo date('Y-m-d', $contract_date)."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$contract_value."<br />";
}
```

the output is:

```
2016-01-01     83.333333333333
2016-02-01     83.333333333333
2016-03-01     83.333333333333
2016-04-01     83.333333333333
2016-05-01     83.333333333333
2016-06-01     83.333333333333
2016-07-01     83.333333333333
2016-08-01     83.333333333333
2016-09-01     83.333333333333
2016-10-01     83.333333333333
2016-11-01     83.333333333333
2016-12-01     83.333333333333
```

Now, what I want is if the contract start date is not starting on first of any month,then I have to calculate for the remaining of the same month and get the other result as same as:

Output I'm looking for:

```
    2016-01-15     83.333333333333
    2016-02-01     83.333333333333
    2016-03-01     83.333333333333
    2016-04-01     83.333333333333
    2016-05-01     83.333333333333
    2016-06-01     83.333333333333
    2016-07-01     83.333333333333
    2016-08-01     83.333333333333
    2016-09-01     83.333333333333
    2016-10-01     83.333333333333
    2016-11-01     83.333333333333
    2016-12-01     83.333333333333
```

So the first date(2016-01-15) should calculate for the date between 15 to last date of same month and the others should go regular as I shown above. Please someone give a suggestion and I have found a way to insert the first 15 days value by doing the following code:

```
$one_month_contract_value = ($contract_value / $contract_start_date_last_date);
echo $one_month_contract_value."<br />";
$initial_contract_value_for_first_month = ($one_month_contract_value*$no_of_days);
echo $initial_contract_value_for_first_month."<br />";
```

This gives me the first month contract value and I can insert this directly into the database. Now how can I proceed to calculate the further months as of first date.

this is the output i get now:

```
2016-01-15     43.010752688172
2016-01-01     83.333333333333
2016-02-01     83.333333333333
2016-03-01     83.333333333333
2016-04-01     83.333333333333
2016-05-01     83.333333333333
2016-06-01     83.333333333333
2016-07-01     83.333333333333
2016-08-01     83.333333333333
2016-09-01     83.333333333333
2016-10-01     83.333333333333
2016-11-01     83.333333333333
```

And the total value is lesser than the contract value.

Comment: I suggest calculating $no_of_days dynamically inside foreach. This code is too complicated to propose examples. I recommend you to separate it on functions, it definitely will help you to find a solution.

Comment: I have wrote few lines for bringing the data between the start date and the end date of start date's month, please check my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how I see it. I hope that idea will help you

```
$contract_start_date = strtotime('2016-01-15');
$contract_end_date = strtotime('2016-12-01');

$contract_start_date_last_date = date('t', $contract_start_date);
echo "contract last date of any start month: ".$contract_start_date_last_date."<br />";
$contract_end_date_last_date = date('t', $contract_end_date);
echo "contract last date of any end month: ".$contract_end_date_last_date."<br />";

$no_of_months = 1 + (date("Y", $contract_end_date) - date("Y", $contract_start_date)) * 12;
$no_of_months += date("m", $contract_end_date) - date("m", $contract_start_date);
echo $no_of_months."<br />";

$total_contract_value = 1000;
$no_of_bookings = 1;
$no_of_records = ($no_of_months / $no_of_bookings);
echo $no_of_records."<br />";

$current_month = $contract_start_date;
for($i = 0; $i < $no_of_records; $i++){
    $contract_start_date_last_date = date('t', $current_month);
    $no_of_days =  $contract_start_date_last_date - date("d", $current_month);

    $contract_value = ($total_contract_value / $no_of_records);
    if ($i === 0) {
        $one_month_contract_value = $contract_value / $contract_start_date_last_date;       
        $contract_value = $one_month_contract_value * $no_of_days;
    }

    echo date('Y-m-d', $current_month)."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$contract_value."<br />";

    $calculated_records = intval($i * $no_of_bookings);
    $current_month = strtotime("+".$calculated_records." months", getStartDateOfMonth($contract_start_date));
}

function getStartDateOfMonth($timestamp) {
    return strtotime(date('Y-m-01', $timestamp));
}
```

Comment: thanks, the output is awesome but Im not getting the contract value for the   first 15days instead it shows for a month. Please check and help

Comment: Its again taking the first month value, check my question i have updated the answer from your code.